# C plus plus about defining static data member in header file or source file

Tags: c++

I defined a class B in `B.h` header file. B has a static data member. I defined this static data member out of class B in header file. But when i built it, errors occur.

> 1. main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static class
>      std::basic_string,class
>      std::allocator > B::b"
>      (?b@B@@2V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?
>      $allocator@D@2@@std@@A) already defined in B.obj
> 2. fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

`B.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef _B_H
#define _B_H
#include <string> 
class B
{
public:
  B();
  ~B();
  static void showfunc();
  static std::string b;
};
std::string B::b = "BBB";
#endif
```

`B.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

B::B()
{

}
B::~B()
{

}
void B::showfunc()
{
  cout<<b<<endl;
}

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  B b_obj;  
  b_obj.showfunc();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_B_H`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// B.h 
#ifndef _B_H
#define _B_H
#include <string> 
class B {
public:
   B();
   ~B();
   static void showfunc();
   static std::string b;
};
#endif

//B.cpp #include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include "MyHeader1.h"
using namespace std; 
B::B(){} 
B::~B(){}

void B::showfunc(){
   cout<<b<<endl;
}

// main.cpp 
#include <iostream> 
#include "MyHeader1.h" 
using namespace std; 
std::string B::b = "BBB"; 

int main(){
   B b_obj;    
   b_obj.showfunc();
   return 0; 
}
```

here your solution

Answer (score 5):

You have defined an static variable in your header file. That works only if the static file is included exactly once! But you included it twice (main.cpp and B.cpp).
Move the following line to B.cpp and it works:

```
std::string B::b = "BBB";
```

Comment: sorry, i can't, someone above had given correct answer too. Maybe next time:)

Answer (score 3):

You need to move definition of `b` to the `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1):

> I defined this static data member out of class B in header file. But when i built it, errors occur.

Then simply don't do that!

Don't define static members in a header. You'll introduce the definition into each TU that `#include`s the header.

Define them in *one* TU instead; the easiest way to do this is in a *.cpp* file.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the definition in a hader file then this definition will be duplicated in each object module that includes this header. So the linker will not know which definition to use and whether these definitions are equivalent.

Comment: i see. Thanks. i move its definition into my source file.